# How use a image as map instead of google map

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

**Hello
is that it is possible to use an image map instead of google map. how can we do
Thank you for any help**

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask some specific question, not an open one. Mention what you are trying to do. How you are planning it to do. Do some searching on web and study the basics before asking a question.

**For your question the answer is "YES you can"**. But you have to do lot of things by yourself. You need to have a large image (collection of images) with required information. Then you have to map  and display them with viewing coordinates and zoom levels etc.... Study how Google do it(search web for that).

Comment: _I've search the web, but I did not find the appropriate answer to my quuestion._

Comment: _I used gmaps4rails to locate my projects on a google map.
I want to do the same thing but with my propore map I built with software QGIS._